# Vue.js best approach to organize API endpoints?

Tags: vue.js

On my components I am having to access my endpoints (API Gateway/Lambda), this is currently requiring me to hardcode this on a per-component level. Obviously not ideal, haha.

Here is an example of what I have now on a Vue component:

```
async mounted() {
    axios.get('https://XXXXXXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/{environment}/{endpoint_name}')
      .then(response => {
        this.data = response.data;
      })
  }
```

Ideally I am trying to find an elegant way of populating these `axios.get()` sections, so I can have a main reference for the execution id and environment (dev/qa/prod/etc).

I am new to Vue.js, so I am struggling to find the ideal approach. Currently my thought would be to create string that pulls from `main.js` then adds onto the `.get` url. Such as `.get(LAMBDA_URL + 'test')`, ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you can abstract away all api calls to their own file, somewhere in an `api` folder. You can then make your own `get`, `post`, `put` and `delete` methods that perform some basic boilerplate stuff like prepending the lambda url and parsing common things such as the status code.

You can go further by only calling these api endpoints in your vuex store if you have one. The nice part of that is that your components are no longer concerned where they get the data from. The implementation of getting the data is all in some `fetch` action somewhere in your store. Your components will use a getter to show things.

```
// api/index.js
import { apiUrl } from '@/config';

function apiRequest(method, url, data, whatever) {
  return axios({
    method,
    data,
    url: `${apiUrl}/${url}`
    // etc
  });
}

export function get(url, data, whatever) {
  return apiRequest('get', url, data, whatever);
}

// etc
```

```
// Component
<template>
  <div>
    {{ data }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'my-component',
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      data: 'animals/birds'
    })
  },

  mounted () {
    this.$store.dispatch('animals/fetchBirds');
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I like the approach, as for the Vuex state storing. I haven't touched Vuex stores, reading up on that all now. Is that a direction you'd recommend for a simple SPA website?

Comment: I love the vuex store. I like to use it when there is any significant amount of data in the application, because it decouples the "data storage" and the "rendering" of the application.

Comment: What I forgot to say is that this is particularly nice when you have two places that display one piece of information (e.g. a list view that displays the basic details of each item, and a detail view that displays everything from a single item). You no longer have to do an api call for both, but can preload all information in the list view and be done with it. It's also nice to not necessarily have to refetch an item if you have previously fetched it, because it is now available in the store and can be pulled from there.